# Giving result from random query in search box

Tags: php, regex, search, pdo

This following script works as long as the keyword/user's query contains single word. When I type 2 words, such as; '`honda brio`', it shows as I wish. But when I type randomly, such as; '`brio honda`'. It does not show anything. 
How can I enable the search result with random query?

```
if (isset($_GET['q'])){
    $kw = $_GET['q'];
    $sql="SELECT * FROM post WHERE title LIKE :kw OR description LIKE :kw OR article LIKE :kw ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $qry=$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $qry->bindValue(':kw','%'.$kw.'%');
    $qry->execute();
    while ($res=$qry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $res['id'];
        $title = $res['title'];
        .....
    }
```

Here's the [live page](https://hondaautoserang.com/search.php?q=brio%20honda).

Comment: You can explode the string 'brio honda' and create a `LIKE` query for every word including the present string. e.g. LIKE 'brio honda' OR LIKE `brio` OR LIKE `honda`

Comment: pls give me real answer to make it clear for me

Comment: @Ayush I think the first part is unnecessary. The desired result will be achieved by `title LIKE '%honda%' AND title LIKE '%brio%'`.

Comment: @mrun I think the first part is to be included as it is the original query. Also OR is needed.

Comment: Well, I still don't agree but it doesn't really matter any more :) If you did it `title LIKE 'brio honda' OR title LIKE '%brio%' OR title LIKE '%honda%'` it would return results which contain the single words `honda` or `brio` but not necessarily simultaneously both. Anyway, as I said it doesn't really matter now :)

Comment: if it's exploded (separated), what if user type: `brio honda otr harga serang di banten bla bla bla`.

Comment: Then you will have a large query that will return all of the user's requested search results.

Comment: lolz ...it's not reasonable i think. any other idea?

Comment: @HermanNz You can probably check out `MySQL's` [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) capability.

Comment: Would you entertain mysql's REGEXP and pipe out your values for each column?

Comment: regex perhaps give solution? pls let me know